# Why is my Magento Catalog Block Preference ignored in di.xml?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, preference, di.xml

I am trying to extend the Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct block in Magento 2.1
My Vendor_ModuleName module has the registration.php, the etc/module.xml and it's enabled.

Then I add an etc/di.xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

I expect the rendering of the catalog listing to break because my module block has not yet been created, however, my catalog seems to render as usual.

Indeed, no matter what I put in my Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct class, it's completely ignored, and this is confirmed by enabling template and block name hints on the storefront: The output block is Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct

What is it that I've missed here?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138183/listproduct-class-override-issue ?

Comment: I tried adding your preference in di.xml file and I get the following error since I have not created that class:

2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct does not exist

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe you have your preference reversed.  The `type` attribute is the base class you want to override, and the `for` attribute is the class you want to render *instead of* the `type`.</s>

So in your case, try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

This is wrong, I was confused.

Comment: I tried to reverse it, but still no effect. However, your suggestion seems contrary to the documentation I've seen so far: `type` should be my extension and `for` the core class that I want to extend, right?

Comment: You are clearing your cache after making configuration changes correct?

Comment: yes, cleared and reindexed

Comment: This is incorrect, The "for" is the class you want to override, and the "type" is the class which is doing the overriding.